# How to trace xkbmap changes?

Tags: ubuntu, xkb, nx

I am running Fluxbox on an Ubuntu (14.04.5) NoMachine server. I have a very simple `startup` file:

```
fluxbox="$HOME/.fluxbox"
stderr="$fluxbox/stderr"
(umask 077; > "$stderr")
exec 2> "$stderr"
setxkbmap de nodeadkeys
exec ssh-agent fluxbox -verbose -log "$fluxbox/log"
```

My problem is, that some process is modifying the xkbmap after I have set it in the startup file. The `nodeadkeys` variant gets lost about one second after I have set it. In order to track this behavior I wrote a trace program, which I start just in front of the `setxkbmap` command. This is my trace script.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
exec > $HOME/setxkbmap.trace
n=${1:-100000}
while ((n>0)); do
  date +"%T.%6N"
  setxkbmap -query 
  n=$((n-1))
done
```

When the script starts the variant is set:

```
$ head -5 setxkbmap.trace 
16:09:04.930663
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     de
variant:    nodeadkeys
```

And after about a second the variant is missing:

```
$ grep -A 5 nodeadkeys setxkbmap.trace | tail -5
16:09:05.864251
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     de
16:09:06.309512
```

How can I figure out, which process is changing the option?